# Calling Stored Procedures with Lots of Parameters

Tags: vba, vb6, adodb

Hey I am getting this error with this piece of code and I am not sure why. It would be a great help as i am trying to make my code slightly earier to read

```
Public Function SaveProperty() As Boolean
'** Save Current Personal Data Record

' Error Checking
On Error GoTo Err_SaveProperty

' Dimension Local Variables
Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset
Dim uPar As ADODB.Parameter

' Check For Open Connection
If uDBase Is Nothing Then
    OpenConnection()
    bConnection = True
End If

' Run Stored Procedure - Save Property Record
uCommand = New ADODB.Command
With uCommand
    .ActiveConnection = uDBase
    .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text))
    .Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("@PropertyManager", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60, cmbPropertyManager.Text)
    .Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("@AddressLine1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30, txtAddress1.Text)
    .Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("@AddressLine2", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30, txtAddress2.Text
'...ETC

.CommandText = "PropertyMaster_SaveRecord"

    .Execute()
End With

' Close Connection
uRecSnap = Nothing
uCommand = Nothing
If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
SaveProperty = True

Err_SaveProperty:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    sErrDescription = Err.Description
    WriteAuditLogRecord("clsProperty", "SaveProperty", "Error", sErrDescription)
    SaveProperty = False
End If
```

End Function

I had reduced the lines of code down from something like this

```
 uPar = .CreateParameter("@LandlordID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append(uPar)
    .Parameters("@LandlordID").Value = Val(lblLandlordID.Text)
```

Comment: What line is your error?

Comment: I just copy/pasted [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78439/overload-resolution-failed-because-no-accessible-append-accepts-this-number-of-a#comment142091_78439). "Add a space in between `.Append` and `.CreateParameter.` Carefully compare what you wrote to what I gave you in my answer on your other question."

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the caveats of the wonderful `With` statement!

As @RubberDuck hinted, your issue is here:

```
.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter(...)
```

Should be:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(...)
```

Without the `With` block, you'd have this:

```
uCommand.Parameters.Append uCommand.CreateParameter(...)
```

`Append` and `CreateParameter` are both members of the `uCommand` object that the `With` block is working with.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make your code easier to read, just do this:

```
' Run Stored Procedure - Save Property Record
Set uCommand = New ADODB.Command  'Note use of Set keyword
With uCommand
    .ActiveConnection = uDBase
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 'Don't need the entire object hierarchy here
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .CommandText = "PropertyMaster_SaveRecord"
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters(1) = cmbPropertyManager.Text 'Collections are usually 1-based in VB6
    .Parameters(2) = txtAddress1.Text
    .Parameters(3) = txtAddress2.Text
    '...ETC
    .Execute()
End With
```

This does require an extra round trip to look up the parameters.  However, if you can afford the performance overhead, this is the easier way to go.  Furthermore, it reduces potential maintenance overhead because it isn't as tightly coupled to the parameter list of the stored proc; for example you can rename the parameters in the stored proc without worrying about breaking your code.

Note also that you don't need to spell out the entire object hierarchy of the enums when you use them; in fact I've never seen it done before.  So not doing that will make your code easier to read as well.

Next, use the Set keyword when instantiating new objects.

Finally, replace this:

```
If uDBase Is Nothing Then
    OpenConnection()
    bConnection = True
End If
```

With this:

```
If uDBase.State = adStateClosed Then
    OpenConnection()
    bConnection = True '?? Probably don't need this, see below
End If
```

The reason that you don't want to rely on checking whether the object is nothing is that you could close the connection somewhere else in your code and forget to set uDBase to nothing.  This can create a very hard-to-find bug.  Also, if the only reason you have a bConnection variable is because you are using it to keep track of whether your connection is open or not, you can safely get rid of it and just use the State property.

A further improvement would be to change your OpenConnection routine to a GetConnection routine, and encapsulate all of your checking for open connections and so on in it.  Like this:

```
Public Function GetConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Static myConn As ADODB.Connection
    If myConn.State = adStateClosed Then
        Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
        myConn.Open "myConnectionString"
    End If
    GetConnection = myConn
End Function
```

This assumes that you are working with one connection throughout your application and that it stays open while your application is running.  This is implied by the scope of your uDBase variable.  There are more economical ways to manage connections, of course, which you might need to look at depending on how much traffic you're dealing with.